# python cannot display formatted error message

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to display error message like this,

```
raise TypeError(
        'no conversion handler defined for value {} of type {}'.format(val, val_type))
```

`val` is `NaT` and `val_type` is `pandas._libs.tslibs.NaTType`, but the error messsage only displays,

```
no conversion handler defined for value {} of type {}
```

I am wondering how to fix the issue.

UPDATE. after updated `pandas` to `0.21.0` and `numpy` to `1.13.3`, running the same code, problem solved.